# Why is boost logging giving me the LNK1104 error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I am trying to learn Boost logging using [this tutorial](https://www.scalyr.com/blog/getting-started-quickly-c++-logging)

So I installed everything listed using NuGet into Visual Studio 2017, but when I try to include trivial.hpp, it gives me this error:

**LNK1104   cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib'**

I've been researching and found something about having to build the headers into .lib files. Am I going in the right direction? If so, how do we do that, preferably using tools that Visual Studio provides? If I'm on the wrong path, what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: library can't be located (path is missing or it is invalid).

Comment: I've been digging around and couldn't find where the lib files are. The confusing thing is that the include folder is inside the lib folder.

Comment: Looks like you configured the library to be linked but Visual Studio can't find the related library. You should add the correct path to folder containing the library in "Linker->General->Additional Library Directories" under Project Settings.

Comment: There is no lib files to be found, so I couldn't give any paths to the linker. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to properly install boost. This usually includes a build step. The libraries are built during this step.

Comment: It seems the libraries installed [this way](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost_log-vc141/) are [prebuilt](https://github.com/sergey-shandar/getboost/blob/master/boost.bat#L57) only for x86 not for x64. you need either to change build target to Win32 or download and build boost manually.

Comment: I figured it out! So it turns out that the tutorial made us download a bunch of other packages beside boost, and those packages are where the libraries are in. I just gave the path to those packages and it worked fine. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need the `boost_log-vc141` package, in addition to `boost` itself. Many Boost libraries are header-only and do not require a `.lib`, but there are some exceptions. Logging is one of them.

**In theory**, NuGet should tell Visual Studio about the library path where it installed downloaded packages. This is more than a bit flaky. NuGet is really a tool for .Net, and its use for C++ is somewhat of an afterthought. I've found that restarting Visual Studio can resolve the LNK1104 error, but this is not the most reliable solution.

The mechanism by which this should work is the `boost_log-vc141.targets` file, which adds a `<AdditionalLibraryDirectories>` property. This is very much a chicken-and-egg design, because this file is *also* stored in the `packages` download directory, even inside the same Boost.Log subdirectory.

This `.targets` file is referenced by the `<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">` section in your `.vcxproj` file.